# Haskell ambiguous type

Tags: haskell, types, primes, ambiguous

```
findMult lst n = [x | x <- lst, x `mod` n == 0]

primes num = 
    let n = [2..num]
        x = ceiling (sqrt num)
        nsqrt = [2..x]
        not_prime = map (findMult n) nsqrt
    in diff2 n (concat not_prime)
```

has the following problem when i try to run it

```
<interactive>:1:0:
    Ambiguous type variable `t' in the constraints:
      `RealFrac t' arising from a use of `primes' at <interactive>:1:0-8
      `Floating t' arising from a use of `primes' at <interactive>:1:0-8
      `Integral t' arising from a use of `primes' at <interactive>:1:0-8
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

I tried using fromIntegral but i don't think i used correctly as that gives me compilation error. Please help.

The purpose of this is to find all the prime numbers up until num.

Comment: I assume `num` should be an `Integral`?

Comment: Try telling the compiler what the types are so that it does not have to guess. Give the type signatures that you expect and then see if there is an error message. The problem here is that you are being to general for your purposes I think; without specifying what you want clearly.

Comment: @Robert: Given that Floating and Integral are very unlikely to be instantiated by the same type, I'd say he's too contradictory, not too general. Being general is not generally a problem. Also except for the monomorphism restriction standard Haskell code will not break because you left out type annotations.

Comment: @sepp2k: Correct code without type annotations will compile and work correctly, yes, but the errors generated by incorrect code are likely to be more confusing if you don't have any type annotations.

Comment: @John: True, but Robert made it sound as if the missing type declarations could cause the error (or at least I read it that way) and I just wanted to clarify that that is not the case.

Comment: @sepp2k you are right there in that it does not the cause of the error. What I was really trying to get at (without outright saying) was that writing out the type would make the types that he is working with obvious and thus if anything was contradictory, or just plain incorrect, then it would become clear.

Comment: It technically could cause the error, since ghci doesn't know which type the function wanted when calling it.  It's usually better to add your types on ghci though (ie. primes (100 :: Integer))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get error messages like this when you use an integral value where a floating value was expected (or vice versa).

In this case the problem is that you're calling `sqrt`, which takes a floating point value as an argument, on `num` making the compiler think `num` is a floating point value. But also use `num` as an upper limit for `n`, which is a list of integral values (because it's used as an argument to `findMult` which needs a list of integral values).

So before calling `sqrt` on `num` call `fromIntegral` on it, like this:

```
x = ceiling (sqrt (fromIntegral num))
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of taking the square root, you can take all squares up to the limit.

```
-- instead of
{- x = ceiling (sqrt num)
   nsqrt = [2..x] -}
-- avoid sqrt
nsqrt = takeWhile (\x -> (x-1)^2 < num) [2..]
-- or even avoid multiplication altogether
nsqrt = map fst . takeWhile ((< num) . snd) . zip [2..] $ scanl1 (+) [1,3..]
```